# adding twig variable in html.html.twig from module

Tags: theming, 8

I'm looking to add a twig variable, which is set in a module, and render it in the html.html.twig template file for my theme.

In my module file I use the hook_preprocess_html() function where I render and set the twig variable like so:

```
function insusite_cta_bar_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
 $output = \Drupal::theme()->render('insusite_cta_bar_actions', array('items' => $itemsOutput, 'panels' => $panelOutput));

 $variables['cta_bar'] = $output;
}
```

Then in the html.html.twig template file in my themes folder I simply render the new cta_bar variable like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html{{ html_attributes }}>
 <head>
  <head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
 <title>{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
  <css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
  <js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
 </head>
 <body{{ attributes }}>
  {{ page_top }}
  {{ page }}
  {{ page_bottom }}
  {{ cta_bar }}
  <js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
 </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't render anything at all.

However, if I add preprocess_html() function to my .theme file then it DOES work, problem is we're using drupal as a multi-site system so I'd have to find a way to add this in to every theme's html, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested what I can of your code, and this works from a custom module:

```
function examplemodule_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

 $variables['cta_bar'] = ['#markup' => '<h2>Test CTA Bar</h2>'];
}
```

It then can be output in the theme with this template:

/themes/custom/mycustomtheme/templates/layout/html.html.twig

like this:

```
{{ cta_bar }}
```

Of course, you need to register your preprocess function by clearing the cache.

Other than that, I think it must be a problem with your theme function insusite_cta_bar_actions.  Can you give us more info on that?

Comment: Right, tried again today, everything seems to work right now like I intended . Don't know what changed, but like you said probably someting else in my fuction was causing this to break.