# How to use short codes with arguments

Tags: 8

I came across [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203986/adding-twig-variable-in-html-html-twig-from-module). That shows how you can get a code like {{ cta }} populated with any data you want, and get that inserted in a template. I want the same sort of solution, but for content. In other words, let's say I have a blog post, I want to be able to add:

```
{{ cta }}
```

or

```
[[ cta ]]
```

or any convention that works. But the end result is that I must be able to populate the variable via code.

**BACKGROUND INFO**

I have a bunch of events on my website. I often write blog posts where I refer to events on the site. To add dynamic content to my blog posts, I'd love to simply add things like:

```
{{ events || from:19dec2014 || to: 23dec2018 }}
```

I would then populate these with the correct information.

Any ideas on how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Shortcode](https://www.drupal.org/project/shortcode) module. It was the among the first hits when I searched for Drupal 8 shortcode.

---

For the second part of your question I'd recommend [Insert View](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_view). You can embed a view via a short code in your content and also pass arguments to it.

> Insert View is a filter that allows users to embed content lists
>   generated by the Views module into node bodies and blocks using
>   relatively simple tag syntax.
>
> Why would you want to use an Insert View tag when you could just
>   invoke a view using PHP? Simple. When you want to allow users to
>   insert views or edit content on a page with an inserted view without
>   granting them permission to use PHP.
>
> The tag syntax is `[view:name=display=args]`
>
> The parameters are: view name, view display id, view arguments.
>
> Valid examples:
>
> - `[view:my_view]` is replaced by the content listing.
> - `[view:my_view=my_display]` invokes the view using the specified display.
> - `[view:my_view=my_display=arg1/arg2/arg3]` invokes the view using the specified display and passes arg1, arg2 and arg3 to the view.
> - `[view:my_view==arg1/arg2/arg3]` passes arg1 to the view and will use the "default" display set for the view.